# Need help for mongoose .find()

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I need the result of Mongoose's `find().exec` in the below format. Is it possible to format the result like that?

```
var myFunction = function(foo, bar) {
  model1.find({ elem: foo, elem2: bar }).exec(function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      /* ... */
    }
    if (data) {
      if (data.passed == true) {
        return { passed: true, point: data.point };
      } else {
        return { passed: false, point: data.point };
      }
    } else {
      return { passed: false, point: "not tried" };
    }
  });
};
```

```
object = {
...
someitem: array.map(function(arr) {
  return {
    _id: program._id,
    title: program.title,
    slug: program.slug,
    status: myFunction(arr._id, arr._id2) /* Like This */
  };
});
...
}
```

and excuse me for My bad english :D

Comment: `find(elem:foo,elem2:bar)` should probably be `find({elem:foo,elem2:bar})`

Comment: From data, you are only returning `{ passed, point}`. Where does user get the array that you've mentioned? And what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You have to return promise from the function in order to get the values which are coming form mongoose query.So change your function to be:

```
var myFunction = function(foo,bar) {
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    model1.find({elem : foo, elem2 : bar}).exec(function (err, data){
     if(err){
       /* Blablabla*/
       reject(err);
     }
     if(data){
       if(data.passed == true){
         resolve({passed:true, point:data.point});
       } else {
         resolve({passed:false, point:data.point});
       }
     } else {
        resolve({passed:false, point:'not tried});
     }
    });
  });
}
```

Than if you want to call the function and get the value you have to do like:

```
let promises, obj_elem = [];

for(let i =0;i < array.length;i++){
  promises.push(myFunction(array[i]._id, array[i]. _id2));
}

/* You can't do it sync manner so you have to use some kind of async process */
Promise.all(promises).then((result)=>{
  for(let i =0;i < result.length;i++){
     obj_elem.push({
        _id: program._id,
        title: program.title,
        slug: program.slug,
        status: result[i].passed 
     });
  }
  console.log(obj_elem); //here you will have values you want
});
```

Comment: ineed use data for like   ``` obj_elem: array.map(function(arr) {
  return {
    _id: program._id,
    title: program.title,
    slug: program.slug,
    status: myFunction(arr._id, arr._id2) /* Like This */
  };
});```

Comment: @Л.Наран you cant use it in sync manner so you have to use methods like call back or promise to solve problem. Updated answer using  promises.

Comment: actually we can't use .push, obj_elem type can't be array obj_elem == element of object, it is like object = {bla1:value, bla2:value, bla3:[bla3_inner1:{ bla3title:value, /*and our object */ obj_elem }, bla3_inner2:{ bla3title:value, /*and our object */ obj_elem }, ]  ..... :D

Comment: i don't know what say it :D